# correct hybrid expression in sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, hybrid

I'm trying to build a simple hybrid expression in SQLalchemy as a tutorial for doing a more complicated expression, but I'm having some trouble getting the basics to work.  I basically have a table in database, that has a column filled with an array of numbers.  I want to sum that column for every row and select only the rows that have a total >= some value, e.g. 1000.  I want to take this sql query

```
select s.* from db.spaxel as s where ((select sum(f) from unnest(s.flux) as f) >= 1000.0);
```

which works, and returns 136 rows out of 1024, and turn it into this SQLalchemy query

```
subset = session.query(db.Spaxel).filter(db.Spaxel.sum >= 1000.0)
```

Here is my SQLalchemy class

```
class Spaxel(Base):
    ... table definition stuff ...

    @hybrid_method
    def sum(self,name=None):
        total = sum(self.flux)
        return total

    @sum.expression
    def sum(cls):
       return select([func.sum(column('totalflux'))]).select_from(func.unnest(cls.flux).alias('totalflux'))
```

when I type

```
print db.Spaxel.sum()
```

I get

```
SELECT sum(totalflux) AS sum_1
FROM unnest(db.spaxel.flux) AS totalflux
```

which looks to be correct.  But when I type

```
print session.query(db.Spaxel).filter(db.Spaxel.sum >= 1000.0)
```

I get

```
SELECT db.spaxel.pk AS db_spaxel_pk, db.spaxel.cube_pk AS db_spaxel_cube_pk
FROM db.spaxel
WHERE true
```

which is not correct.  And my SQLalchemy query returns the full set of 1024 rows.  Any ideas on what is the problem?